# stopping 'sed' after match found on a line; don't let sed keep checking all lines to EOF

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a text file in which each a first block of text on each line is separated by a tab from a second block of text like so:

```
VERBS, AUXILIARY. "Be," subjunctive and quasi-subjunctive   Be, Beest, &c., was used in A.-S. (beon) generally in a future sense.
```

In case it is hard to tell, tab is long space between "quasi-subjunctive" and "Be".

So I am thinking off the top of my head a 'for' loop in which a var is set using 'sed' to read the first block of text of a line, upto and including the tab (or not, doesn't really matter) and then the 'var' is used to find subsequent matches adding a "(x)" right before the tab to make the line unique. The 'x' of course would be a running counter numbering the first instance '1' incrementing and then each subsequent match one number higher.

One problem I see is stopping 'sed' after each subsequent match so the counter can be incremented. Is there a way to do this, since it is "sed's" normal behaviour to continue on thru without stop (as far as I know) until all lines are processed.

Comment: How do you decide what to search for in the first place? It sounds to me that you basically have a two column file (separated by the tab) and you want to sequentially number lines where the first field is the same as some reference field (but the second potentially different). What isn't clear is how you decide what the reference field is. Sample input and output would be helpful.

Comment: @Emmet: because the two blocks of text are separated by a tab I simply use the tab to delimit the first and that becomes the search pattern.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. We have a file with, say, 2,000,000 lines, where each line has a “left hand side” (LHS) and a “right hand side” (RHS) separated by a tab. “The LHS is the search pattern” is confusing because there are 2,000,000 LHSs. Suppose there are 1,000 distinct LHSs. Is the objective to *group* the RHSs by the contents of the LHS? That is, each LHS corresponds to between 1 and 1,999,001 RHSs (but 2,000 on average)?

Comment: @Emmet: yeah I knew my question was probably worded oddly b/c I couldn't quite see the solution I needed until thinking about it afterward. I should have more explicitly expressed how I intended to read the LHS of each line into a var that checks for the same pattern on the rest of the lines, which I did finally manage to figure out how to do using grep to control the line checks: lN=$(sed -n "${sedLnCnt} p" sGNoSecNums.html|sed -r 's/^([^\t]*\t).*$/\1/')

Comment: @Emmet: so a file with 2M lines will require grep to do 2M checks (gulp!): one for each LHS, but sed will only have to make edits to as many lines as there are found duplicate LHS's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got the job done with this little (or perhaps big if too much overkill?) script I whipped up:

```
#!/bin/bash

sedLnCnt=1
while [[ "$sedLnCnt" -lt 521 ]] ; do
    lN=$(sed -n "${sedLnCnt} p" sGNoSecNums.html|sed -r 's/^([^\t]*\t).*$/\1/') #; echo "\$lN: $lN"
    lnNum=($(grep -n "$lN" sGNoSecNums.html|sed -r 's/^([0-9]+):.*$/\1/')) #; echo "num of matches: ${#lnNum[@]}"
    if [[ "${#lnNum[@]}" -gt 1 ]] ; then        #'if' 
        lCnt="${#lnNum[@]}"
        ((eleN = $lCnt-1)) #; echo "\$eleN: ${eleN}"    # var $eleN needs to be 1 less than total line count of zero-based array 
        while [[ "$lCnt" -gt 0 ]] ; do
            sed -ri "${lnNum[$eleN]}s/^([^\t]*)\t/\1 \(${lCnt}\)\t/" sGNoSecNums.html
            ((lCnt--))
            ((eleN--))
        done
    fi
    ((sedLnCnt++))
done
```

Grep was the perfect way to find line numbers of matches, jamming them into an array and then editing each line appending the unique identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `IFS` to `TAB` character and read the line into variables. Something like:

```
$ while IFS=$'\t' read block1 block2;do 
   echo "block1 is $block1"
   echo "block2 is $block2"
done < file
block1 is VERBS, AUXILIARY. "Be," subjunctive and quasi-subjunctive
block2 is Be, Beest, &c., was used in A.-S. (beon) generally in a future sense.
```

Comment: +1 One minor thing: The IFS can be set to a TAB character not `\t`.